# Elasticsearch не ищет по вхождению

Tags: elasticsearch

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы строку **СПС Консультант Бюджетные организации (базовый выпуск)** можно было найти по запросу **бюджет**
Находит по **бюджетные**, **бюджетн**. Не находит по **бюджет**, **бюдже**

Также находит строку **Москва Проф** по запросу **москв** и не находит по запросу **моск**

Индекс строится таким образом

```
    $settings = [
        'settings' => [
            'number_of_shards' => 1,
            'number_of_replicas' => 1,
            "analysis" => [
                'analyzer' => [
                    'my_stop' => [
                        "type" => "russian",
                        "tokenizer" => "standard",
                        "stopwords" => "_russian_"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'mappings' => $this->_mapping ?? $this->createMap(),
    ];
```

Маппинг вот такой

```
$default = [
        "properties" => [
            "uid_content" => ["type" => "text"],
            "body" => [
                "type" => "text",
                "analyzer" => "my_stop",
                "term_vector" => "with_positions_offsets"
            ],
            "title" => [
                "type" => "text",
                "analyzer" => "my_stop",
                "term_vector" => "with_positions_offsets"
            ],
            "tags" => ["type" => "text", "fielddata" => true],
            "type_content" => ["type" => "text", "fielddata" => true],
            "author_name" => ["type" => "text"],
            "dt" => ["type" => "date", "format" => "yyyy-MM-dd"],
            "link" => ["type" => "text"],

        ]
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить `token filter` со стеммером и триграммами, и индекс по триграммам. Не проверял, но может сработать.

```
"filter": {
    "ru_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "russian" 
    },

    "tokenizer": {
        "trigrams": {
            "type": "ngram",
            "min_gram": 3,
            "max_gram": 3
    }
},

"analyzer": {
    "ru_analyzer": {
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": ["lowercase", "ru_stemmer"]
    },

    "ru_trigrams": {
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": "trigrams"
    }
}
```

Comment: Я все это добавил в секцию analisis и получил ошибку. Если в секции filter секцию trigrams вынести на уровень выше, то ошибка исчезает, но это не решает проблему.

Comment: А как ищите? Приведите пример запроса.